# MySQL - Select by some "tags", include all tags

Tags: mysql

I've successfully managed to fetch articles filtering by matching tags in an AND manner.

This is my current code:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles a
JOIN article_tags a_t ON a_t.article_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = a_t.tag_id
WHERE t.caption IN ('fire', 'water', 'earth')
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.caption) = 3
```

Where:

- **articles** are the articles I want to fetch, with id, title, etc…
- **tags** are the list of tags, with id and caption
- **article_tags** a relationship table, with article_id and tag_id

Now The problem is that after matching, I want to retrieve all the tags that each article has. Even if they are matched by 3 different ones, one may have 5 tags, other 4 tags, and I want them included in each row. Something like "tag,tag,tag" or whatever I can parse, in some "tags" column.

Any ideas? I can't find a way around it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to join your query as a subquery with a query that returns all the tags and combines them with `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

```
select a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.caption) tags
from (select distinct a.*
      from articles a
      JOIN article_tags a_t on a_t.article_id = a.id
      JOIN tags t on t.id = a_t.tag_id
      WHERE t.caption IN ('fire', 'water', 'earth')
      GROUP BY a.id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.caption) = 3) a
JOIN article_tags a_t on a_t.article_id = a.id
JOIN tags t on t.id = a_t.tag_id
GROUP BY a.id
```

BTW, there's no reason to use `LEFT JOIN` in your query, because you only care about rows with matches in `tags`.

I also wonder about the need for `DISTINCT` in the `COUNT()` -- do you really allow multiple tag IDs with the same caption?

Comment: Thank you! However, I am only getting one result row now. Any thoughts? P.S: Left Join and Distinct notes: Because I am a noob xD hah.

Comment: Fixed. I was missing the GROUP BY in the subquery (because I copied it from your question, which was also missing it).

Comment: Works like a charm. And I've learned GROUP_CONCAT now. Thank you sir. So I did not intend to use DISTINCT. Tag names are unique. By removing it, it will work just fine, right?

Comment: Yeah, You added it to be extra safe, so did I :)